# fileIn, fileOut errors - I can't figure it out

Tags: c#, file

I have been working on this for two weeks now and I know that I am missing something small. I have to modify an old project into an new one. The first project was if someone entered their work type (ex: w for worker, s for supervisor, m for manager, etc), their age, and experience. The program would tell them if they could retire. If they couldn't retire, it told them what they needed to fix in order to retire.

The new program must take a fileIn and make a fileOut displaying the workers ID, age, experience, and eligibility. After all is displayed then they want the average of age and experience.

My teacher is a stickler for having modular headings and Main on top. I entered the code below into my 2015 studio and I end up getting three error messages. The fileIn is also below. The Util is a reference from my teacher and I don't know how to copy it in.

Can anyone give me any advice? I am completely green and new to coding so I am not into all the terms yet so I apologize in advance.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Util;

namespace Program_9
{
class Program
{
    const string INPUT_FILE_NAME = "C:\\Users\\Programing 1\\Soluation 1\\Program 9\\Retirement Numbers\\Input";
    const string OUTPUT_FILE_NAME = "C:\\Users\\Programing 1\\Soluation 1\\Program 9\\Retirement Numbers\\Output";

    static string lineIn;
    static StreamReader fileIn;
    static StreamWriter fileOut;
    static char WType, WElig;
    static uint id;
    static double WAge, WExp;
    static double numOfEmployees;
    static double AvgAge, AvgExp, AgeAvgTotal = 0.0, WAge1Total = 0.0, WAge2Total = 0.0, WAge3Total = 0.0, WAge4Total = 0.0, WAge5Total = 0.0;
    static double WAge6Total = 0.0, WAge7Total = 0.0, WAge8Total = 0.0, WAge9Total = 0.0, WAge10Total = 0.0, WAge11Total = 0.0, WAge12Total = 0.0;
    static double ExpAvgTotal = 0.0, WExp1Total = 0.0, WExp2Total = 0.0, WExp3Total = 0.0, WExp4Total = 0.0, WExp5Total = 0.0;
    static double WExp6Total = 0.0, WExp7Total = 0.0, WExp8Total = 0.0, WExp9Total = 0.0, WExp10Total = 0.0, WExp11Total = 0.0, WExp12Total = 0.0;

    static void Main()
    {
        OpenFiles();
        PrintReportHeadings();
        while ((lineIn = fileIn.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            ParseLineIn();
            PrintDetailLine();
            UpdateTotals();
        }
        CalcAvg();
        PrintAvg();
        CloseFiles();
        DspData();
    }

    static void OpenFiles()
    {
        if (File.Exists(INPUT_FILE_NAME))
        {
            fileIn = File.OpenText(INPUT_FILE_NAME);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} was opened", INPUT_FILE_NAME);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0} does not exit\n", INPUT_FILE_NAME);
            ConIO.Exit();
        }
        if (File.Exists(OUTPUT_FILE_NAME))
        {
            fileOut = File.CreateText(OUTPUT_FILE_NAME);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} was created\n", OUTPUT_FILE_NAME);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0} could not be created\n", OUTPUT_FILE_NAME);
            ConIO.Exit();
        }
    }

    static void PrintReportHeadings()
    {
        fileOut.WriteLine("Employee  Age  Experience  Eligibility");
        fileOut.WriteLine("{0,9},  {1,7},  {2,7}, {3}", id, WAge, WExp, WElig);
        fileOut.WriteLine();
        fileOut.WriteLine("Average {0,7:}, {1,7}", AvgAge, AvgExp);
    }
    static void ParseLineIn()
    {
        string[] words = new string[4];

        lineIn = lineIn.Trim();
        while (Regex.IsMatch(lineIn, "[ ]{2}"))
            lineIn = lineIn.Replace("  ", " ");
        words = lineIn.Split(' ');
        id = UInt32.Parse(words[0]);
        WType = char.Parse(words[1]);
        WAge = int.Parse(words[2]);
        WExp = int.Parse(words[3]);
    }

    static void PrintDetailLine()
    {
        fileOut.WriteLine("{0} {1,7:d} {2,7:d} {3,7:d} {4,7:d} {5,3}",
            id, WAge, WExp, WElig);
    }

    static void UpdateTotals(int WAge1, double WAge2, double WAge3, double WAge4, double WAge5, double WAge6, double WAge7, double WAge8, double WAge9, double WAge10, double WAge11, double WAge12, double WExp1, double WExp2, double WExp3, double WExp4, double WExp5, double WExp6, double WExp7, double WExp8, double WExp9, double WExp10, double WExp11, double WExp12)
    {
        numOfEmployees++;
        WAge1Total += WAge1;
        WAge2Total += WAge2;
        WAge3Total += WAge3;
        WAge4Total += WAge4;
        WAge5Total += WAge5;
        WAge6Total += WAge6;
        WAge7Total += WAge7;
        WAge8Total += WAge8;
        WAge9Total += WAge9;
        WAge10Total += WAge10;
        WAge11Total += WAge11;
        WAge12Total += WAge12;
        AgeAvgTotal += AvgAge;
        WExp1Total += WExp1;
        WExp2Total += WExp2;
        WExp3Total += WExp3;
        WExp4Total += WExp4;
        WExp5Total += WExp5;
        WExp6Total += WExp6;
        WExp7Total += WExp7;
        WExp8Total += WExp8;
        WExp9Total += WExp9;
        WExp10Total += WExp10;
        WExp11Total += WExp11;
        WExp12Total += WExp12;
        ExpAvgTotal += AvgExp;
    }

    static void CalcAvg(int WAge1, double WAge2, double WAge3, double WAge4, double WAge5, double WAge6, double WAge7, double WAge8, double WAge9, double WAge10, double WAge11, double WAge12)
    {
        AgeAvgTotal = (WAge1 + WAge2 + WAge3 + WAge4 + WAge5 + WAge6 + WAge7 + WAge8 + WAge9 + WAge10 + WAge11 + WAge12);
        AvgAge = AgeAvgTotal / numOfEmployees;
        AvgExp = ExpAvgTotal / numOfEmployees;
    }

    static void PrintAvg()
    {
        fileOut.WriteLine(" ");
        fileOut.WriteLine("Avg {0,7:f} {1,7:f}", AvgAge, AvgExp);
    }

    static void CloseFiles()
    {
        fileIn.Close(); fileOut.Close();
    }

    static void DspData()
    {
        switch (WType=WElig)
        {
            case 'W':
            case 'w':
                if (WAge >= 63 && WExp >= 25)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} Employee can retire.", id, WAge, WExp);
                else if (WAge >= 63 && WExp < 25)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} Employee cannot retire due to lack of experience.", id, WAge, WExp);
                else if (WAge < 63 && WExp >= 25)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} Employee cannot retire due to being underage.", id, WAge, WExp);
                else if (WAge < 63 && WExp < 25)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} Employee cannot retire due to being underage and lack of experience.", id, WAge, WExp);
                break;
            case 'S':
            case 's':
                if (WAge >= 60 && WExp >= 24)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} Employee can retire.", id, WAge, WExp);
                else if (WAge >= 60 && WExp < 24)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} Employee cannot retire due to lack of experience.", id, WAge, WExp);
                else if (WAge < 60 && WExp >= 24)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} Employee cannot retire due to being underage.", id, WAge, WExp);
                else if (WAge < 60 && WExp < 24)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} Employee cannot retire due to being underage and lack of experience.", id, WAge, WExp);
                break;
            case 'M':
            case 'm':
                if (WAge >= 55 && WExp >= 20)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} Employee can retire.", id, WAge, WExp);
                else if (WAge >= 55 && WExp < 20)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} Employee cannot retire due to lack of experience.", id, WAge, WExp);
                else if (WAge < 55 && WExp >= 20)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} Employee cannot retire due to being underage.", id, WAge, WExp);
                else if (WAge < 55 && WExp < 20)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} Employee cannot retire due to being underage and lack of experience.", id, WAge, WExp);
                break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is the fileIn:

```
1235 W 45 20
2536 W 55 21
5894 W 60 30 
4597 W 75 35
2597 S 35 10
5689 S 40 20
5489 W 55 39
5872 M 60 40
5569 M 55 25
5566 W 80 20
8865 M 59 35
5598 S 65 35
```

Here are the errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required    formal parameter 'WAge1' of 'Program.UpdateTotals(int, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double)'  Program9.1  C:\Users\Programing 1\Soluation 1\Program 9\Program9.1\Program9.1\Program.cs    37  Active
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'WAge1' of 'Program.CalcAvg(int, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double)'  Program9.1  C:\Users\Programing 1\Soluation 1\Program 9\Program9.1\Program9.1\Program.cs    39  Active
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning CS0649  Field 'Program.WElig' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value  Program9.1  C:\Users\Programing 1\Soluation 1\Program 9\Program9.1\Program9.1\Program.cs    20  Active
```

Comment: `UpdateTotals` is defined as: `UpdateTotals(int WAge1, double WAge2, double WAge3, double WAge4, double WAge5, double WAge6, double WAge7, double WAge8, double WAge9, double WAge10, double WAge11, double WAge12, double WExp1, double WExp2, double WExp3, double WExp4, double WExp5, double WExp6, double WExp7, double WExp8, double WExp9, double WExp10, double WExp11, double WExp12)`.  You're calling it simply as `UpdateTotals();`... you need to provide the parameters to the function call. this is just one of the errors, there are more.  The compiler is giving you the information you need to fix.

Comment: The first error is telling you that `UpdateTotals()` expects arguments to be passed in to it.  So you'd have to change your `UpdateTotals();` line so that **every** single value it expects is passed in: `UpdateTotals(x, y, z, etc);` where x, y, z, etc are the proper variable names you've declared.

Comment: 24 parameters... dear lord...

Comment: This is why you don't write methods with ridiculous numbers of parameters like that.

Answer (score 2):

1. You have a call `UpdateTotals();` in your Main method but this `UpdateTotals` is not parameterless (far from it actually, it takes a bunch of required parameters.)
2. The same is true for `CalcAvg`
3. This is just a warning, the code will still compile without fixing this.

Regarding your design: I better option would be for your method to take an object and have this object define properties that you want to do something with. Having this many parameters on one method is just asking for problems later down the road. If you find they are all of the same type and the position of the parameters does not matter then you should pass in an array of that type instead.

```
void UpdateTotals(int WAge1, double WAge2, double WAge3, double WAge4, double WAge5, double WAge6, double WAge7, double WAge8, double WAge9, double WAge10, double WAge11, double WAge12, double WExp1, double WExp2, double WExp3, double WExp4, double WExp5, double WExp6, double WExp7, double WExp8, double WExp9, double WExp10, double WExp11, double WExp12)
```

would become

```
void UpdateTotals(int WAge1, double[] WAges);
```

If `WAge1` is actually also a double then change the whole thing to

```
void UpdateTotals(double[] WAges);
```

If you have multiple arrays then define a new type that has those as properties and pass that instead.

```
public class SomeContainer {
  public double[] WAges {get;set;}
  public double[] WExps {get;set;}
}

void UpdateTotals(SomeContainer wContainer);
```

@Abion47  pointed out that maybe WAge and WExp are related. In that case update the model to reflect that.

```
public class WContainer {
  public double WAge {get;set;}
  public double WExp {get;set;}
}

void UpdateTotals(WContainer[] ws);
```

Comment: My suggestion is that since every `Age` parameter has a corresponding `Exp` parameter, a better design would be to use something like `void UpdateTotals(params Tuple<double, double>[] employees)` where `Item1` corresponds to the age and `Item2` corresponds to the experience.

Comment: @Abion47 - if that is the case then that would be a better design.

Comment: I haven't learned arrays yet, what does 'get' and 'set' stand for? WAge and WExp are related. I have to figure out how to  accumulate totals for age, exp, and number of employees in order to display the average age and experience. I would like to use the "void UpdateTotals(double[] WAges);" but it doesn't like the 'WAges'

Comment: I changed WAge = int.Parse(words[2]); WExp = int.Parse(words[3]); to double.Parse, and WAge1 to double.

Comment: Now I only have one error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1501 No overload for method 'CalcAvg' takes 24 arguments Program9.1 C:\Users\Programing 1\Soluation 1\Program 9\Program9.1\Program9.1\Program.cs 39 Active